# Condition on $s$ for $\iint_{(a,b)^2}\frac{1}{|x-y|^s}dxdy < \infty $

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multiple-integral

I am trying to find the set of real numbers $s\in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$\iint_{(a,b)^2}\frac{1}{|x-y|^s}\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y < \infty$$
where $(a,b)$ is an arbitrary finite open interval of $\mathbb{R}$. For now, except for the trivial case $s\leq 0$, I am not able to solve the problem.

My intuition is that as for the one dimensional case, I should have $s<1$ for the integral to converge, but i do not know how to prove it.

Comment: Have you tried some changes of variables to turn your intuition into a proof?

Comment: Or better yet, what happens when you integrate directly?

Comment: I just tried, and indeed I see that it diverges for $s>1$. The reason is that in this case, when I directly integrate the equation, I end up with "$-\frac{2}{y-y}$", so I need $s<1$ so that the $x-y$ after integration goes up. Thank's !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $b>a$, with the change of variables $x=\frac{b-a}{2}u+\frac{b+a}{2}$ and $y=\frac{b-a}{2}v+\frac{b+a}{2}$ we can write
$$
\iint_{(a,b)^2}\frac{1}{|x-y|^s}\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y
{
=
\iint_{(-1,1)^2}\frac{1}{(\frac{b-a}{2})^s|u-v|^s}\frac{(b-a)^2}{4}\mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v
\\=
(\frac{b-a}{2})^{2-s}\iint_{(-1,1)^2}\frac{\mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v}{|u-v|^s}.
}
$$
By defining $A=\{(u,v):u^2+v^2<1\}$ and $B=\{(u,v):u^2+v^2<2\}$, we have
$$
{
A\subseteq(-1,1)^2
\quad,\quad
(-1,1)^2\subseteq B.
}
$$
Therefore
$$
\iint_{A}\frac{\mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v}{|u-v|^s}
\le
\iint_{(-1,1)^2}\frac{\mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v}{|u-v|^s}
\le
\iint_{B}\frac{\mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v}{|u-v|^s}.
$$
Also
$$
\iint_{u^2+v^2<1}\frac{\mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v}{|u-v|^s}
{
=
\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\frac{r\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\theta}{r^s|\cos\theta-\sin\theta|^s}
\\=
2^{-\frac{s}{2}}\int_0^1r^{1-s}\mathrm{d}r
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{|\sin\theta|^s}
\\=
2^{2-\frac{s}{2}}\int_0^1r^{1-s}\mathrm{d}r
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{(\sin\theta)^s}.
}
$$
The latter integral converges when $s<1$ and diverges when $s\ge 1$. Therefore

> When $b>a$, $\iint_{(a,b)^2}\frac{1}{|x-y|^s}\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$ converges if $s<1$ and diverges if $s\ge 1$.

Answer (score 0):

The command of Mathematica 13.2 on Windows 10

```
Integrate[1/RealAbs[x - y]^s, {x, a, b}, {y, a, b}, 
 Assumptions -> s \[Element] Reals && a \[Element] Reals && b \[Element] Reals && a < b && s < 2]
```

results in $$\frac{2 (a-b)^2 (b-a)^{-s}}{(s-2) (s-1)} $$

and the command

```
Integrate[1/RealAbs[x - y]^s, {x, a, b}, {y, a, b}, Assumptions ->  s \[Element] Reals && a \[Element] Reals && b \[Element] Reals && a < b && s >= 2]
```

says the integral diverges.